# Retrieving data from db: how to consider only date in datetime field?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I hava a table with `t.string :created_time` column

It contains data in UTC format (e.g. `2017-05-10T06:30:01+0000`)

I have to retrieve records from table with certain date but time doesn't matter

```
date = Date.new(2017,05,10)
nodes = Node.where(created_time: date)
logger.info nodes.count
```

Here I have `0` count. How to make additional processing of `created_time` value so I could to compare only *date* part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a date range and query like this

```
date = Date.new(2017,05,10)
nodes = Node.where(created_time: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)
```

You will get the records for that day ;)

**UPDATE**

Why on earth is `created_at` a `string`??

Let's try this,

```
Node.where('DATE(nodes.created_time) = ?', date)
```

Comment: actually I made a migration to convert string column into datetime. then I used first option

Answer (score 0):

Select the date as just date from mysql table like this

```
SELECT DATE(date_time_field) FROM `yourtable`;
```

Comment: No idea, how do you fetch the data from mysql in ruby?

Comment: `nodes = Node.where(created_time: date)` for example. So it is pointed it the question

Comment: try this `Node.where(Date(created_time): date)` @IlyaBlokh

Comment: I see, you somehow need to tell ruby to call it like this, or may be do it on application layer using date format, the worst case is to write a stored procedure that would return the formatted date.